# How identify the primary video card on Linux programmatically?

Tags: linux, bios, xorg

The primary video card usually can be set in the BIOS (option *Primary VGA card*), and it will be the first card used by the system.

My question is how can I programmatically identify (using a shell script and utilities is preferable) which of my two video cards is the primary card?

**Edit:** I was hoping that I wouldn't have to elaborate *why* I need this, because it is a bit complex, but I will explain the problem below.

I have a *configuration wizard* which allows the dynamic configuration of a multiseat system in a LiveCD, with two independent displays, keyboards and mice, my *wizard* works in this way:

1. Start one Xorg server per video card (after generating xorg.conf with the correct PCI bus ID).
2. Start a *ui* in each of Xorgs with messages for configuration (press key and press mouse). One *seat* can be configured each time.
3. After the first *seat* is configured, the *wizard* closes the first Xorg and start the definitive Xorg in this *seat* with the desktop environment (already with the correct keyboard and mouse set).
4. The second seat now is able to be configured (press key and mouse), after this pass **3** is repeated for seat two.

The problem is: If I start the first Xorg in the primary video card, everything works, but if I start the first Xorg in the secondary card this is what happens:

The passes 1, 2, and 3 works, but at the end of pass 3, when the Xorg of the first seat is closed, the Xorg of the second seat blinks and doesn't come back, just show a blank screen with a **_** cursor at top, the desktop of the first seat loads, but I don't see the wizard screen in the second seat, the first Xorg just comes back if I execute a *kill -HUP* , and I need to start the *ui* from it again.

So, it is why I need to identify the primary video card before I can start Xorg (sorry I didn't mention this before). I tested this system in different computers, with different video cards and the behavior is the same. I also tested with the lasted packages of the kernel and Xorg in Ubuntu 12.04 (packages of the *raring* release).

Comment: I elaborated my question, see the edit.

Comment: What happens when you get a system that has the ability to use onboard video (IGP) until the power of a full strength GPU is needed, as in a laptop with power saving enabled?

Comment: @JimR, may be I don't have undestood your question, but all systems where I tested have a onboard vga and a PCI vga, but the primary VGA is configurable in the BIOS and I get the list of vgas with the command lspci, so the order of the vgas are always the same in the lspci, if the primary vga is the first in the lspci, will work, if don't, not work. I don't tested this system in a laptop with dual vga, I don't have one and is not my intent for this system.

Comment: @Msum: I think that JimR is thinking of e.g. [Nvidia Optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus) in marketing parlance...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: You are correct. :)  I couldn't think of the marketing name to save my life.

Comment: The primary card is listed in the xorg log file. You can parse the log after running `Xorg -probeonly`.

Comment: Good thing you elaborated, I'd be interested in having a look at your LiveCD/wizard -- fiddling with multiseat, livecds and distro building for 10+ years :-)

Comment: @MichaelShigorin This was part of a project that I worked a long time ago as a junior, it is available at github in the account of the organization for which I worked, but I warn you that is not a project for general use, it was a livecd for specific use and was based in Ubuntu 12.04, so I don't know if it still able to build a ISO image, you can see here: https://github.com/UFSC/moodle-provas-livecd-provas

Comment: @MichaelShigorin The problem mentioned in the question here was never addressed, I had to generate a bootmenu with two options, each one for start the first Xorg in one specific videocard, the user would try the first one and if not work, he should reboot and try the second one. The wiki of this repository have the description, but all that wiki is written in brazilian portuguese. The system is all based in shell scripts and some python code. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming X11 is running, you could suppose that primary card is the one used by `Xorg`... then you might try

```
 ls -l /proc/$(pidof X)/fd |grep /dev/dri
```

on my system Debian/Sid/x86-64 with Linux 3.12 kernel (which has an Nvidia card on a Intel3770K which also has its VGA) I'm getting `/dev/dri/card0` etc...

But you should explain really why you are asking and what problem do you want to solve.... Why does that matter to you?

I am not at all sure that Linux has a notion of primary graphic card like the BIOS knows it.

And probably `hwinfo` is telling you everything about your graphical cards.

Comment: Sorry I don't cited this before, but I need to know which is the primary video card before I can start a Xorg. I elaborated my question, see the edit.

Comment: I did some more tests today and without success yet. The info in /proc/dri/0 would be the answer, but sadly is not reliable, in one machine there is info for both vgas in /proc/dri/0/name and /proc/dri/1/name, in another there is nothing, `cat /proc/dri/0/name` returns a empty string. The hwinfo have a awkward info, the `hwinfo --gfxcard` show in the last line the info _Primary display adapter: #33_, but the adapter #33 is not the primary, looking at _/proc/dri_, is the card 1, not the card 0.

Comment: There is more, in my tests I figured out that /proc/dri/0 do not means is the primary vga card, the info there, always is the same in my machine test, wherever I change the primary video card in the BIOS the card0 have the same BUS ID. And in the _hwinfo_ the primary display adapter are always the same too, so, none of theses options have the answer, still without a way to detect the primary video card in linux.

Comment: In arch linux you $(pidof X) need to be replaced with $(pidof Xorg). Yes, if there are monitors attached to several gpus, then there will be links to both cards. And yes, card0 does not mean primary gpu. My intel gpu always stays card0 and amd stays card1, nevertheless I change primary gpu option in uefi.

Answer (score 1):

There are several command line tools in Linux that give you human readable information from the BIOS. Maybe you can find your Video boards in there and see which one is made primary. From what I see in my output, it does not look like something says "this is the primary video", but I do see quite a lot of information. You could output that information to a file when video card A is primary, again when B is primary, then compare those two files and see whether there is a difference.

The command I used, which gives me a lot of information, is `dmidecode`:

```
sudo dmidecode | less
```

If you look at the manual page:

```
man dmidecode
```

You will notice that the programmers offer a few other similar tools such as `biosdecode` and `vpddecode`.

From those you learn that the BIOS information is available from the /dev/mem device. Although you need to be root to read it, if you know the address (I don't) then you could go in there and peek and poke as required to find out where that one information of which video card is defined as the primary video card.

Running dmidecode, there are some details about my motherboard:

```
Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
  Manufacturer: Supermicro
  Product Name: X9SCI/X9SCA
  Version: 1.01
  Serial Number: ZM25U44192
  Asset Tag: To be filled by O.E.M.
  Features:
    Board is a hosting board
    Board is replaceable
  Location In Chassis: To be filled by O.E.M.
  Chassis Handle: 0x0003
  Type: Motherboard
  Contained Object Handles: 0
```

Here I have one video entry:

```
Handle 0x000E, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
  Type: Video
  Status: Enabled
  Description:    To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

Then the other entry looks like this:

```
Handle 0x0036, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
   Reference Designation:  Onboard IGD
   Type: Video
   Status: Enabled
   Type Instance: 1
   Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0
```

It could also be something you need to read from the Flash memory your BIOS uses. This is done with flashrom (that you may need to install):

```
sudo flashrom --programmer internal --read my-flash.bin
```

In my case the ROM on my computer is 2Gb of data. So quite large. However, you can be sure that the information you are looking for exists within that data block since that is the only mean for the BIOS to save data that will stay around when the computer gets turned off.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way how to check the primary GPU when they are from different vendors or at least have different names.

In KDE go to *Info Center*, then open Graphics -> OpenGL. In *Direct Rendering (GLX)* and *Direct Rendering (EGL)* you can see a *Driver* block. You can see the *Vendor* and *Device* there. It will name the GPU which is primary.

At this screenshot you can see that AMD gpu is primary:
[image]

Also, you can get that *Vendor* value programmatically by running
`glxinfo | grep "OpenGL vendor string" | cut -f2 -d":" | xargs`.

I guess this method will stop working when kde will switch to vulkan for rendering (in kde 6). But for now I do not know another method of determining primary gpu.

Comment: Do not know it it has something to do with primarity, but `drm_info | grep nodes` returned 
`Available nodes: primary, render` twice, for both GPUs. So it looks like it is not that.